# C++ class defined after a struct that contains a list of that class

Tags: c++, list, class, declaration

I have a parent virtual class (and its childs, but these are not the problem)

```
//---------------------------------------------------------------------
class TPowerComponent
{
public :
    int X, Y, Rotation;
    __fastcall TPowerComponent( PowSymbType AType );
    __fastcall TPowerComponent( TStream& S );
    virtual void __fastcall Store( TStream& S );
    __fastcall ~TPowerComponent();
    virtual void __fastcall Paint(TCanvas * Canvas, const WorkSheetInfoRec& WSInfo);        // se dessine
};
```

One of its methods (paint) use a WorkSheetInfoRec struct, which is defined above by:

```
struct WorkSheetInfoRec {
    int WSOpt, Study;
    std::list<TPowerComponent*> NetWorkList;
};
```

The problem is that this struct use a list of objectz that are of the parent class which has a method (paint) that also refer to a struct that use the list...
So the compilation fails because each one must be declared before the other..
How can I deal with that in a header file.

Thanks

Comment: Just *declare* one of them without *defining* it!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a forward declaration:

```
class TPowerComponent;
struct WorkSheetInfoRec {
    int WSOpt, Study;
    std::list<TPowerComponent*> NetWorkList;
};
```